# LOAD DATA INFILE To Import CSV File Into Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

As a workaround, I am trying to use this syntax to import my csv file into my database table instead of `fgetcsv` because files uploaded may be quite big. So I made this:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("dbtest",$connect);

$filename = $file_path;

$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename'
        INTO TABLE tbltest
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        (@rcode, @pcode, @mcode, @bcode, @ecode, @filetype, @rec_count, @ges_count, @ck_count, @ic_count, @ran_count);" ;

        //echo $sql;
        mysql_query ($sql,$connect) ;
```

Now, the problem is nothing is inserted in my table. When I do `echo $sql`, the result is this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'uploads/testfile.csv' INTO TABLE tbltest FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@rcode, @pcode, @mcode, @bcode, @ecode, @filetype, @rec_count, 
@ges_count, @ck_count, @ic_count, @ran_count);
```

The testfile.csv looks like this:

```
01|01|01|01|0000|FORM1|5|5|5|||||||||
01|01|01|01|0000|FORM2|238|238||||||||||
01|01|01|01|0000|FORM4|0|||||||||||
01|01|01|01|0000|FORM5|1|||||||||||
01|01|01|01|0000|FORM3|3|3||||||||||
```

Comment: There is nothing in your error logs?

Comment: did you check: "For security reasons, when reading text files located on the server, the files must either reside in the database directory or be **readable by all**. Also, to use LOAD DATA INFILE on server files, you must have the **FILE privilege**. See Section 6.2.1, “Privileges Provided by MySQL”. For non-LOCAL load operations, if the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory."?

Comment: I am currently doing this in my localhost and File Privilege are Checked

Comment: Sorry, I don;t get it :( What does it means you are running in local host?

Comment: Are you running the php script on the same server as the database server? `LOAD DATA INFILE` runs on the MySQL server side and the file path given must be either absolute or relative to the server's data directory.

Comment: @JulioSoares, Sir, I edited the code, added the connection to the database. I am running this code in my localhost (127.0.0.1), and upon checking I have File privileges checked.